# Android Dropdown Settings Menu

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

I'm trying to customize the settings menu or create something with that functionality. I currently have a Toolbar with the title  and a Settings button (with custom icon). This button opens a PopupMenu this way:

```
btnOpenMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(HomeActivity.this, view){
            @Override
            public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(@Nullable OnMenuItemClickListener listener) {
                super.setOnMenuItemClickListener(listener);
            }
        };

        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu);
        popupMenu.show();


    }
});
```

The popup menu is working but I need now to customize the view, at least to make it full width and center the text, as shown in the image:

[image: dropdown menu]

Is it possible to do this with a popup menu? how can I extend the width of the menu and make it full width?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ListPopUpWindow` for this. The advantage is you can customize the layout inside it to put list of strings with images also and etc. Try using this code.

```
ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;
setUpListpopupWindow();
btnOpenMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        listPopupWindow.show();
    } 
});
```

Set your list popup window here.

```
public void setUpListpopupWindow() {
    listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(BluetoothActivity.this);
    listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(btnOpenMenu);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    listPopupWindow.setWidth(metrics.widthPixels); //sets width as per the screen.
    listPopupWindow.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
    listPopupWindow.setModal(true);

    View filterLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_awesome_custom_layout, null);

    listPopupWindow.setPromptView(filterLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead using pop menu for making it full width and center the text. Which I dont think is really easy.

Why dont you use [Bottom Sheets](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html).

There are lots of open source libraries available.Make use of it.